# Print embedded image in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can print an image that is located on disk like so:

```
    void PrintImage(PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        string image = "logo.png";
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(image);
        System.Drawing.Point loc = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 750);
        ev.Graphics.DrawImage(img, loc);  
    }
```

But I want to embed the image into my exe and also print it.
I have added the file to my solution in Visual Studio 2013 and set the Build Action to **"Embedded Resource"**.

Then I have attempted to do the following based on this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287676(v=vs.71).aspx

```
    void PrintBusinessDetails(PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        System.Reflection.Assembly thisExe = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        System.IO.Stream file = thisExe.GetManifestResourceStream("logo.png");

        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(file);
        System.Drawing.Point loc = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 750);
        ev.Graphics.DrawImage(img, loc);  
    }
```

BUT the 'file' is always null.

How can I do this??

**EDIT - Solved**

The following works:

1. Add the file from Resources-->Add Existing file. Call it e.g. "logo".
2. Change Persistence to "Embedded in .resx"
3. Use the following code:

   ```
   void PrintImage(PrintPageEventArgs ev)
   {
       System.Drawing.Point loc = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 750);
       var bmp = new Bitmap(TestPrint.Properties.Resources.logo);
       ev.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, loc);  
   }
   ```